# The base module should not have the 'split' attribute set in the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, bundle, dynamic-feature-module

I want to generate bundle for my project which includes three dynamic features , and this error occured while generating bundle.
also there is no 'split' attribute in my whole porject manifest anywhere , and the project is run on debug mode, successfully. but generating bundle not working.

any suggestion is welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after 3 hours searching and finding Nothing , I decided to see that when exactly this log is generated by google inside building process of bundle. and I found out that it is creating the module with name `base` which will be used to merge all feature modules.
and also I Myself have one feature module in my project with the name of `base`, I wondered if there will be any conflict with this name that occurs this issue . so I refactored and renamed my own `base` module to baseCore and TADA ! everything works well . finally I must say , Hey google fu.. you and your fu..ing developers with your bullsh..t system which always waste our times because of ridiculous problems and cock&bull story generated logs and hints.